# How to return nested list elements and use them in order in python?

Tags: python, list, function

```
def main_func():
   chunk= [["ABABA","ACA"],["AGAGA","AAVA"],["XBX","ARAA"],["AADA","AAA"],["BABAB","ABA"]]
   for a in chunk:
      return a
```

I want to call each lists that is in the chunk list every function call..

```
   def call_list():

   ....
   ....
   .... 

   a=main_func()
   call_list()
```

However I get only one `["ABABA","ACA"]` list.

What can I do to call every list in chunk list ?

Comment: Use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), i.e. the `yield` keyword instead of `return`. When you use `return`, your function exits for good. The rest of your code is not completely clear to me, but one problem is definitely that your loop in `main_func` ends after one iteration.

Comment: voting to close. it's ridiculously unclear what the expected behaviour is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your function into a generator:

```
def gen_chunks():
    chunks = [["ABABA","ACA"],["AGAGA","AAVA"],["XBX","ARAA"],
              ["AADA","AAA"],["BABAB","ABA"]]
    for chunk in chunks:
        yield chunk
```

and use `next()` instead of calling the function:

```
>>> chunks = gen_chunks()
>>> next(chunks)
['ABABA', 'ACA']
>>> (chunks)
['AGAGA', 'AAVA']
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you had an a variable:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,[1, 1, 1, 1, 2,[1, 1, 1, 3,4]]] The code above will still give you the last element.

>>> a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,[1, 1, 1, 1, 2,[1, 1, 1, 3,4]]]
>>> a[-1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, [1, 1, 1, 3, 4]]
>>> a[-1][-1]
[1, 1, 1, 3, 4]
>>> a[-1][-1][-1]
4
```

Hope this helped!